# Android AsyncTask executes with isCancelled()=true when the screen is off

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I' m having an asynctask executed in onCreateView in a fragment. When the screen is off and somehow the fragment should be displayed, the asynctask starts but with the isCancelled() is true. I used PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK but the problem is not solved.
Thanks in advance.

Here is a sample code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        activity = getSherlockActivity();
        context = activity.getApplicationContext();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

        DownloadXMLTask = new DownloadXML(getActivity());
        DownloadXMLTask.execute(file);

        return view;
    }

private class DownloadXML extends AsyncTask<File, Integer, String> {

        private Activity activity;

        public DownloadXML(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() { 
            ... Do stuff ...
        }

        protected String doInBackground(File... files) {
            // Check if the task is cancelled
            if (isCancelled()) { return null; }

            ... Do stuff ...
            ... Do stuff ...
            ... Do stuff ...

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ... Do stuff ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            ... Do stuff ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've described what the behaviour is, but not what behaviour you actually want.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I need the task to be executed as expected the same when the screen is on. It should be cancelled only when the user cause cancel.

Comment: @adamioan : When the "screen is off" your `Activity` and any `Fragments` will no longer be in a running state. If you want to do background processing such as downloads then use a `Service`.

Comment: @Squonk: All the other methods of the fragment are triggered normally, even the asynctask starts. The problem is that when the doInBackground is called isCancelled is true. If the screen is on, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run something regardless of whether your activity is running, it has to be in a service. Probably it's easiest to get started with an `IntentService`, which automatically processes each intent in a background thread. From the activity, make an intent that describes the work to be performed, and `startService` your service using this intent. Give your intent's `onHandleIntent` the code that's currently in your `doInBackground`. You can have it deliver the result back to the activity in a broadcast, or via some other mechanism such as by updating a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to solve this issue by adding the asynctask execution code in **onResume** rather **onCreateView**. The first time the code runs will be cancelled but when the user turns screen on, the **onResume** will re-execute the async task.